# How do I remove a part of a string from an entire column, if I want to remove all the values before a ","?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my first time asking a question here, so apologizes if the formatting is off.

I have a dataset that has a column for a client ID and another one for the age, but when I uploaded the data through pandas, it automatically started indexing the age column. I would like to get rid of the additional numbers before the actual age.

Here's how it turned out:

```
Age : Client ID
1,56   A134
2,61   A35
3,34   B56
4,54   B74
```

And here's how I want it to look:

```
Age : Client ID
56    A134
61    A35
34    B56
54    B74
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please include a sample of the code you are using to get this result.

Comment: something like `df['Age'] = df['Age'].str.replace('\d+,','')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you need only the last values, it can be achieved with `apply`:

```
df["Age"].apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[-1])
```

Comment: `df['Age'].str.split(",").str[-1]` one shouldn't use apply unless absolutely reqd, even faster should be `[i.split(",")[1] for i in df['Age']]`

Comment: Thx! Didn't know about the second `str`